# How to use locally built Svelte 3 compiler in locally running Svelte REPL site?

Tags: svelte

I'm playing around with Svelte and cloned it from its Github repository. I can run the REPL from site directory, but it uses Svelte from unpkg url. I would like to try my locally built compiler and use it instead of the unpkg version. So far I could not find any steps/references. Please guide me with the steps to make it work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I also asked this question in Svelte Discord forum and got the right directions. Actually the information is available inside the `svelte/site` directory `README.md` file. But, since I was expecting it on the main `README.md`, I could not locate it. As it was not obvious (to me and so for few others), I would like to document the steps here.

```
# Steps to build Svelte and use it in REPL site

git clone https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte.git
export PUBLISH="publish" 
cd svelte
npm install
npm run dev
cd site
npm install && npm run update
npm run dev

Point your browser to http://localhost:3000/repl?version=local
```

Comment: does not work any more :)